Is it possible to update String Catalog file dynamically?
I am trying to localise my app using String Catalog, the problem I am facing is all the strings(label/button title) are downloaded from the server. For e.g their is a label which has the text "I am dynamic label" this text is getting loaded from the server. How can I localise it in my app, as at the time of development I don't what the text would be. Is there any way I can parse the String Catalog as json file and update it via code.
I tried reading it first but it's not working.
func readStringCatalog(fileName: String) {
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "xcstrings") else { return nil }

guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }

guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) else { return nil }
        if let jsonDict = jsonData as? [String:Any] {
            return jsonDict
        }
        return nil
}


Why would you need a string catalog if the localisation is done by the server? Just use whatever the server gives you as the buttons' titles.

was checking if it's doable or not?

No. The string catalog is compiled into .strings files and copied into the bundle. Things in the bundle are read-only.
